# sql error, this type of clause was previously parsed

Tags: php, mysql

I try to write the php file to insert data into my database. But I got the errors.

This type of clause was previously parsed. (near "FROM" at position 233)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "FROM" at position 233)

Here is the code

```
INSERT INTO Game(date,teamone_id,teamtwo_id) SELECT
            '$array[4]',
            tid 
            FROM Team 
            WHERE teamName='$array[2]'
            OR teamName='$array[3]',    
            tid 
            FROM Team 
            WHERE teamName='$array[2]'
            OR teamName='$array[3]'
```

Comment: You can't have more `WHERE` of `FROM` clauses in SQL query this way.

Comment: So what is the correct syntax?

Comment: Use `AND` or `OR` to combine multiple conditions.

Comment: @user6428015: see the SQL basics https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html

Comment: But I have three columns in my table, if I use AND or OR to combine them, how can I fill in three columns?

Comment: Your two `WHERE` clauses are the same. The order of tests in `OR` doesn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have multiple `WHERE` clauses. It looks like you're trying to get a cross product, you need to use a self-JOIN.

```
INSERT INTO Game (date, teamone, teamtwo)
SELECT '$array[4]', t1.tid, t2.tid
FROM Team AS t1
CROSS JOIN Team AS t2
WHERE t1.teamName = '$array[2]'
AND t2.teamName = '$array[3]'
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM Game AS g
    JOIN Team AS t1 ON t1.tid = g.teamtwo
    JOIN Team AS t2 ON t2.tid = g.teamone
    WHERE t1.teamName = '$array[2]'
    AND t2.teamName = '$array[3]'
    AND g.date = '$array[4]'
)
```

The `NOT EXISTS` check tests for an existing row with the team IDs reversed.

Comment: But how can I fill in three columns?

Comment: See my updatd answer.

Comment: Thank you for your help. But if I use JOIN, how can I check the duplicate element? Like in these two team columns, 'a b' is same as 'b a', and I suppose to remove 'b a'.

Comment: This just picks one combination. `teamone` is `$array[3]` and `teamtwo` is `$array[4]`.

Comment: Yes. But say, first we pick teamone=a, teamtwo=b, we insert it to the database. Then, we pick teamone=b, teamtwo=a. In my project, this means duplicate, I suppose to avoid this, so I should not insert this into database. So how can I check the duplicate element?

Comment: I've added a check for that duplicate.